# I am getting the selectected item value -1 in dropdown list and not showing the actual value

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am getting the selectected item  value -1 in dropdown list and not showing the actual value

```
  if (ddlperiodunit.Text.Trim() != "Till Further Order")
  {
      if (txtDt.Text.Trim() == "")
      {
          MessageBox("DEBARMENT START DT CAN NOT BE BLANK");
          txtDt.Focus();
          return;
      }
      if (TxtDebarmentPrd.Text.Trim() == "" || TxtDebarmentPrd.Text.Trim() == "0")
      {
          MessageBox("DEBARMENT PERIOD CAN NOT BE BLANK");
          TxtDebarmentPrd.Focus();
          return;
      }
  }
```

I am selecting `"Till Further Order"` in my drop down list but while debuging sometimes its shows `ddlperiodunit.Text.Trim() =-1`

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Did you tried to set AutoPostback='true' property for your DropDownlist ? please take a look at [AutoPostBack](https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-dropdownlist-autopostback.html) for more info.

Comment: Show us the way you fill the dropdownlist (Events, Datasource or AddItems...)

Comment: And also In what event the code that you show is placed